# How many ways are there to choose non-repeating numbers that add up to $N$?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to find a formula for the number of ways (and maybe an easy road to find those ways) to find all the sets $A$ of natural numbers $A_i\in\mathbb{N}<N$, such that no numbers in $A$ repeat and the numbers in $A$ add up to $N\in\mathbb{N}$. I have no idea how to find this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of numbers do you want?

Comment: Sorry, naturals.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A000009

Comment: Actually, http://oeis.org/A111133 is more like it, as you specify $A_i < N$.

Comment: $A_i\in\mathbb N\lt N$?? What does $\mathbb N\lt N$ mean??

Answer (score 2):

We have for the unlabeled set operator

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SET(\mathcal{A})}$$

by the exponential formula the OGF

$$\exp
\left(\sum_{\ell\ge 1} (-1)^{\ell-1} \frac{A(z^\ell)}{\ell}\right).$$

In the present case $$A(z) = z+z^2+\cdots = \frac{z}{1-z}$$

so that we find

$$Q(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} Q_n z^n =
\exp\left(\sum_{\ell\ge 1} (-1)^{\ell-1}
\frac{1}{\ell} \frac{z^\ell}{1-z^\ell}\right).$$

We now build a recurrence. We have $Q_0 = 1$ and get

$$[z^{n-1}] Q'(z) = n Q_n
\\ = [z^{n-1}] \exp\left(\sum_{\ell\ge 1} (-1)^{\ell-1}
\frac{1}{\ell} \frac{z^\ell}{1-z^\ell}\right)
\sum_{\ell\ge 1} (-1)^{\ell-1}
\frac{z^{\ell-1}}{(1-z^\ell)^2}
\\ = [z^{n-1}] Q(z) \sum_{\ell\ge 1} (-1)^{\ell-1}
\frac{z^{\ell-1}}{(1-z^\ell)^2}
= [z^{n-1}] Q(z) \sum_{\ell= 1}^{n} (-1)^{\ell-1}
\frac{z^{\ell-1}}{(1-z^\ell)^2}
\\ =  \sum_{\ell= 1}^{n} (-1)^{\ell-1}
[z^{n-\ell}] \frac{1}{(1-z^\ell)^2} Q(z)
=  \sum_{\ell= 1}^{n} (-1)^{\ell-1}
\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/\ell \rfloor -1}
(q+1) Q_{n-(q+1)\ell}
\\ =  \sum_{\ell= 1}^{n} (-1)^{\ell-1}
\sum_{q=1}^{\lfloor n/\ell \rfloor}
q Q_{n-q\ell}
= \sum_{p=1}^n Q_{n-p}
\sum_{\ell|p} (-1)^{\ell-1} \frac{p}{\ell}.$$

This finally yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
Q_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{p=1}^n Q_{n-p}
\sum_{\ell|p} (-1)^{p/\ell-1} \ell.}$$

This will produce the sequence

$$1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 18, 22, 27, 32, 38,
\\ 46, 54, 64, 76, 89, 104, 122, 142, 165, 192, 222, 256, 296,
\ldots $$

which  does indeed  point to  [OEIS A000009](http://oeis.org/A000009).
[OEIS   A111133](http://oeis.org/A111133)   is    then   obtained   by
inspection.

**Remark.** An alternative representation of

$$p \sum_{\ell|p} (-1)^{\ell-1} \frac{1}{\ell}
\quad\text{is}\quad
\sum_{\ell|p \wedge \ell\;\mathrm{odd}} \ell =
\sigma_{\mathrm{odd}}(p).$$

To see this write $p= 2^{v_2(p)} m$ to get

$$2^{v_2(p)} m \sum_{q=0}^{v_2(p)}
\sum_{\ell|m} (-1)^{\ell 2^q-1} \frac{1}{\ell 2^q}
\\ = 2^{v_2(p)} m
\sum_{\ell|m} (-1)^{\ell-1} \frac{1}{\ell}
+ 2^{v_2(p)} m \sum_{q=1}^{v_2(p)}
\sum_{\ell|m} (-1)^{\ell 2^q-1} \frac{1}{\ell 2^q}
\\ = 2^{v_2(p)} \sigma_{\mathrm{odd}}(p)
- 2^{v_2(p)} m \sum_{q=1}^{v_2(p)}
\sum_{\ell|m} \frac{1}{\ell 2^q}
= 2^{v_2(p)} \sigma_{\mathrm{odd}}(p)
- 2^{v_2(p)} m \sum_{\ell|m} \frac{1}{\ell}
\sum_{q=1}^{v_2(p)} \frac{1}{2^q}.
\\ = 2^{v_2(p)} \sigma_{\mathrm{odd}}(p)
- \sigma_{\mathrm{odd}}(p)
\sum_{q=1}^{v_2(p)} 2^{v_2(p)-q}
= 2^{v_2(p)} \sigma_{\mathrm{odd}}(p)
-  \sigma_{\mathrm{odd}}(p) (2^{v_2(p)}-1) 
\\ = \sigma_{\mathrm{odd}}(p).$$

A slightly  different version of  the same  proof goes like  this (put
$v_2(p) = v$):

$$\sum_{\ell|p} (-1)^{p/\ell-1} \ell
= \sum_{q=0}^v \sum_{\ell|m} (-1)^{2^v m/\ell/2^q-1} \ell 2^q
\\ = \sum_{\ell|m} (-1)^{m/\ell-1} \ell 2^v
+ \sum_{q=0}^{v-1} \sum_{\ell|m} (-1)^{2^v m/\ell/2^q-1} \ell 2^q
\\ = 2^v \sigma_{\mathrm{odd}}(p)
- \sum_{q=0}^{v-1} \sum_{\ell|m} \ell 2^q
= 2^v \sigma_{\mathrm{odd}}(p)
- \sum_{\ell|m} \ell  \sum_{q=0}^{v-1} 2^q
\\ = 2^v \sigma_{\mathrm{odd}}(p) - (2^v-1) \sigma_{\mathrm{odd}}(p)
\\ = \sigma_{\mathrm{odd}}(p).$$

**Addendum.** We may use the alternate form of $Q(z)$ which is

$$Q(z) = \prod_{m\ge 1} (1+z^m).$$

This yields

$$Q'(z) = Q(z) \sum_{m\ge 1} \frac{m z^{m-1}}{1+z^m}.$$

We obtain

$$[z^{n-1}] Q'(z)
= [z^{n-1}] Q(z) \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{m z^{m-1}}{1+z^m}
= \sum_{m=1}^n [z^{n-m}] \frac{m}{1+z^m} Q(z)
\\ = \sum_{m=1}^n
\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/m \rfloor - 1}
m (-1)^q [z^{n-m-qm}] Q(z)
= \sum_{m=1}^n
\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/m \rfloor - 1}
m (-1)^q Q_{n-(q+1)m}
\\ = \sum_{m=1}^n
\sum_{q=1}^{\lfloor n/m \rfloor}
m (-1)^{q-1} Q_{n-qm}
= \sum_{p=1}^n \sum_{q|p} \frac{p}{q} (-1)^{q-1}  Q_{n-p}
\\ = \sum_{p=1}^n Q_{n-p} \sum_{q|p} (-1)^{p/q-1} q.$$

We may then continue as before.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(n,k)$ be the number of sets of $k$ natural numbers summing to $n$. You want to find $\sum_{k=2}^{\sqrt{2n}} f(n,k)$. The reason for the $\sqrt{2n}$ in the upper bound is that any set of $k$ numbers will have sum at least $k(k+1)/2$; therefore, there is no need to consider sets of size $\sqrt{2n}$ or larger.

I claim that
$$
f(n,k) = f(n-k,k)+f(n-k,k-1)
$$
To see this, let $x_k>x_{k-1}>\dots>x_1$ be $k$ numbers summing to $n$. If $x_1>1$, then
$$
x_k-1,x_{k-1}-1,\dots,x_2-1,x_1-1
$$
is a set of $k$ numbers summing to $n-k$. If $x_1=1$, then the above list with $x_1-1$ removed is a list of $k-1$ numbers summing to $n-k$.

This recursion gives you an algorithm to compute $f(n,k)$ for all $2\le k\le \sqrt{2n}$ via dynamic programming using $O(n^{3/2})$ additions.